# How to secure my asmx web methods only to be called by my asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, web-applications, asmx

I have a web application which is having an asmx web service holding some web methods. Those are being called through jQuery ajax method to get data or do various operations.

I want it to be accessed by only my web application and no other ways to call the web methods and this should be a fully secured one.

Can any body suggest on what are the security threats might affect my web methods and how i can protect them from those threats ?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: [Surely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775594/) [you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866653/how-do-i-secure-asp-net-web-service-to-only-allow-relative-path-calling) [have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855902/c-sharp-webservice-and-android-app-how-prevent-illegal-accesses) [tried](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400198/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-access-to-an-asmx-webservice-i-e-the-asmx-page-and) [to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672506/how-can-i-programatically-limit-access-to-a-webservice)  [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067326/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using session state then you can use this

```
 [WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]
```